# iPod Nano 2G audio started skipping during music playback - what causes this?

Tags: ipod, music, performance

My 5 year old iPod Nano "2G" 8GB has recently began skipping during song playback.  It sounds like when a CD skips, a kind of digital glitching sound.  But lately it's gotten really bad, where it will skip repeatedly over a whole verse of a song.

I did some research and found that it's actually possible for [Flash memory to get fragmented](http://blog.condusiv.com/post/2007/06/22/The-Impact-of-Fragmentation-on-Flash-Drives-(iPods-Jump-Drives-etc).aspx). Does this really apply to my iPod Nano?

It is significant to mention **this skipping just started happening as I've recently filled the iPod full to capacity.**

How can I resolve it?  I have a Windows XP computer.  Would I really want to Defragment this iPod like you would with a spinning hard disk?  Would I be safe to simply Cut & Paste everything off the iPod's drive letter in Windows Explorer?  (Move it all temporarily to my hard drive, and then restore it?)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered an issue similar to this on my iPhone, both on the 4S and 3GS. It took an embarrassingly long time to diagnose my headphones as the issue. I have a set of Sennheiser earphones with an inline remote, and if the jack becomes damaged, internal wires can get crossed and can start sending commands to the iPod application. I found that the play button would get hammered repeatedly as a result, and caused playback to stutter.

So, if your earphones have an inline remote and a damaged jack, try changing them. You might find a fix is cheaper than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Taking all data *off* the Nano and reinstalling everything might work around the fragmentation issue but I'm not sure how this could relate to the skipping you hear.

Have you tried working through [iPod nano (2nd generation) Troubleshooting Assistant](http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/five_rs/nano2gen/) already?

Comment: No I haven't done the 5 R's, mainly because this iPod has always been Manually Managed and thus, it is the only place my metadata (Play Counts, Ratings, Playlists, etc.) exist.

I will try Resetting it and then playing the songs I recall skipping badly.  It is interesting they were songs I added most recently, and therefore would be the most likely candidates to be the most fragmented songs on the iPod...

I just really didnt think that Flash memory could lose performance due to fragmentation, and I'm still not certain.